# How do i convert a date in varchar (1-Jan-2020) to date type in DB2 sql?

Tags: sql, date, db2, varchar

I have a column with dates as below in my db2 table.

```
4-Jan-2020
7-Sep-2020
7-Dec-2020
```

I  want to convert them to

```
2020-01-04
2020-09-07
2020-12-07
```

respectively. How do I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Is your column datatype - date?

Comment: no it is varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On recent versions of DB2, use `TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT DATE(TO_DATE(date_col, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
FROM yourTable;
```

**Data:**

```sql
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '4-Jan-2020' AS date_col UNION ALL
    SELECT '7-Sep-2020' UNION ALL
    SELECT '7-Dec-2020'
)
```

Comment: `DATE()` is rather redundant.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Funny, if you poke around this site for similar questions, many of the accepted answer seem to wrap the call to `TO_DATE` with another cast to `DATE()`.  Not sure why they are doing this.

Comment: Confusingly, `TO_DATE` does not return a `DATE` in Db2, rather it returns a `TIMESTAMP`, hence it often is a good idea to cast the result to a date.  The reason for this oddity is (I belive) that TO_DATE came into Db2 as part of it's Oracle compatibility, and `TO_DATE` in Oracle returns a date+time datatype (which Oracle, very confusingly, names DATE https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413)

Comment: I have some junk strings in my column, thats giving error. How do i convert them to NULL and rest all to date?

Comment: Use: `CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(date_col, '[0-9]{1,2}-[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}') THEN DATE(TO_DATE(date_col, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) END`

Comment: for some reason all of em are coming as null, it should match '21-Dec-2020' varchar right?

Comment: ok figured out, missed the lower case. Thanks ```CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(date_col, '[0-9]{1,2}-[A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{4}') THEN DATE(TO_DATE(date_col, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) END```

Comment: Oops...didn't see that you have mixed case months names, yes, use your version `:-)`